# Configure multiple `make` development environments in Vim

Tags: vim

What's the best way to set up multiple "development environments" in Vim, including settings like `errorformat` and `makeprg`?

For instance, I normally right C code using GCC as the compiler/linker and Scons as the build tool, so I set `makeprg=scons` and configure `errorformat` appropriately for GCC. However, right now I'm righting Java using maven, so I want to set `makeprg=mvn` and configure `errorformat` differently. There may also be other options like indent style, mappings, and commands that I want to set depending on what I'm working on.

So what I'm looking for is a way to issue a single command to effectively say "now I'm working on C", or "now I'm working on Java", etc., and configure the appropriate settings. Is the easiest thing to just define a command/function to do this, or is there a better way?

Comment: I'm wondering if something similar to `undo_ftplugin` would be helpful for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a whole set of *compiler plugins* exactly for this reason, and a `:compiler` command to set it. So I can just right my own compiler plugin to set the options I want. For reference, these are stored in (for instance) `\vim74\compiler\`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in your `vimrc` to change local settings when the filetype changes (which happens when you load a new buffer):

```
if has("autocmd")
    autocmd FileType c     setlocal makeprg=mvn      errorformat=this
    autocmd FileType java  setlocal makeprg=whatever errorformat=that
endif
```

If you'd prefer this to be manual instead of automatic based on detected file type then set up keyboard mappings instead (see `:help map-commands`).